# odoo13 TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution(Chatter to an existing model)

Tags: typeerror, odoo, python-3.6

I got the problem ,can anybody help me? thanks
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution

> ```
> class StockQuant(models.Model):
>    _name = 'stock.quant'
>    _inherit = ['stock.quant', 'mail.thread']
> ```

> **manifest**.py

> ```
>    'category': 'Report',
>    'version': '0.1',
>
>    # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
>    'depends': ['base', 'sale', 'web','mail','product','stock'],
> ```

Error

> ```
>  File "odoo13\source\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 221, in load
>    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
>  File "odoo13\source\odoo\models.py", line 504, in _build_model
>    ModelClass.__bases__ = tuple(bases)
> TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
> order (MRO) for bases Model, mail.thread, stock.quant, base
> ```

Comment: >  File "odoo13\source\odoo\models.py", line 504, in _build_model
>    ModelClass.__bases__ = tuple(bases)
>TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
>order (MRO) for bases Model, mail.thread, stock.quant, base

Comment: Do you have modules `stock` and `mail` in your module's manifest file?

Comment: YES, as follows. 
    'depends': ['base', 'sale', 'web','mail','product','stock'],

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop of dependencies here, **sale** depends on **sales_team** that already depends on **base** and **mail**, **stock** already depends on **product** too.

You need to remove base, mail, and product.

Comment: remove mail? we need to extend mail.thread

Comment: keep the same error after "You need to remove base, mail, and product".

Comment: That is not really a loop. A loop would be 2 modules depending on each other. If you want to change data (views, menus, etc.) of `sale` and `sales_team` you have to depend on both of them, even if logically it should be sufficient to only have one of them as dependancy.

Comment: please help  ,I have the error for a few days

Comment: please try to delete the "_name = 'stock.quant'"